# Non zero code returned when installing project docker ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I tried to install a project from docker and after running the command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --build
```

at step 5 I'm receiving a Connection timed out saying:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to download.icu-project.org port 80: Connection timed out
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c curl -sS -o /tmp/icu.tar.gz -L http://download.icuproject.org/files/icu4c/60.1/icu4c-60_1-src.tgz     && tar -zxf /tmp/icu.tar.gz -C /tmp     && cd /tmp/icu/source     && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local     && make     && make install' returned a non-zero code: 7
```

I tried running into bash, but when I type 'docker-compose ps' I got no containers so I don't know how to properly fix this.
Have any of you encounter this issue and want to share with me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is evident from the ERROR, the url that's being accessed as part of the docker-compose i.e. http://ftp.lfs-matrix.net/pub/blfs/conglomeration/icu/icu4c-60_1-src.tgz is inaccessible which is why the docker-compose fails with timeout. You can try accessing the URL from the browser and yes its unreachable.

You must change it to something else something like http://ftp.lfs-matrix.net/pub/blfs/conglomeration/icu/. While you do that please make sure that you are indeed downloading the zip from a reliable source.